# create a Regex that won't replace substrings

Tags: python, regex, string, logic

I have the following problem:

given a dictionary where the keys are strings which I will find in another string, and the values are the strings that I want to replace the keys with: for example

```
replace_dict = {"p": "r"}
str = "p"
str = replace(str, replace_dict)
print(str)  # Should output r.
```

now I have the following code:

```
pattern = re.compile("|".join(sorted(rep.keys(), key=len, reverse=True)))
ret_string = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], ret_string)
```

Now this code does the job, however it has one bug: it replaces substrings for example:

```
replace_dict = {"p": p1}
str = "p=>p1"
str = replace(str, replace_dict)
print(str)  # outputs "p1=>p11", but the output should be p1=>p1
```

now... I'm trying to figure out how I can tackle this problem without making my regex too complicated.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that the string must be equal to the key (no other characters) for replacement or that the key must be a "word" on its own in the string to be replaced (where "word" may need further definition)?

Comment: In your last example, it appears that you actually do want it to replace a substring, as the first `p` (before the `=>p1`), while a prefix, is still a substring of your `str = "p=>p1"`. Do you mean you only want the first full match to be replaced? Is `=>` a special separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is word boundaries which in regex are \b.

Here is a fixed code:

```
with_boundaries = map(lambda x: "\\b" + x + "\\b", rep.keys())
pattern = re.compile("|".join(sorted(with_boundaries, key=len, reverse=True)))
ret_string = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], ret_string)
```